# Why is "On Most Surfaces" titled the way that it is given that only one surface appears in the song itself?

Tags: song-lyrics, title, the-gathering

Loosely related: [Are there two separate narrators in "On Most Surfaces" by The Gathering?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/3503/are-there-two-separate-narrators-in-on-most-surfaces-by-the-gathering)

The song *On Most Surfaces* by The Gathering (on their *Nighttime Birds* album) has the following lyrics:

> The frost hits me in the eye and wakes me
>   These are blurry winters and I cannot see
>
> I walk into the white light of the snow
>   When the sun comes
>   I break it with my shadow
>   Which tells me where I go
>
> The frost hits me in the eye and wakes me
>
> I am the snow falling down on you
>   I tear up your face with my frost
>   And make you run to somewhere warm
>   When I come I see you get away
>   I burst out about your emptiness

This only appears to describe a single "surface" (evidently a snow-covered landscape). That being the case, why is this titled "On Most Surfaces"? What's the significance of the title?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me preface this by saying I have no knowledge of the song or its writers/performers beyond the information in the question.

You say

> this only appears to describe a single "surface" (evidently a
>   snow-covered landscape)

Firstly, a landscape is made up of any number of surfaces, lawns, fields the tops of walls, roads, paths, the roofs of houses, the ledges of a windowsill, the boughs of a tree, the tips of the pales of a fence....

But I think you may be off-beam on assuming that the 'most surfaces' relates to snow, snow generally lands on the upper or windward surface of things, whereas *frost*, which is mentioned more often in the lyric, forms on tops, sides, undersides and edges, in fact... on most surfaces.

At a guess, perhaps the lyric was inspired by a report on weather conditions, in my part of the world the phrasing is usually something like 'widespread frost except in sheltered glens', but perhaps elsewhere there are warnings of *frost on most surfaces*.